# Mysql Query INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have the following 2 tables :

**Lead**

```
LEADid
pmp
pms
ci_lead
av_lead
prod_lead
f_lead
sec_lead
pid
```

**TeamMember**

```
UID
fname
lname
email
d_phone
h_phone
```

All the data in the Lead table are int() that correspond to a UID from the TeamMember table.

So what I am trying to do is, say I select a row from the Lead table using the PID as my key, I want to pull all the fname and lname from TeamMembers that match the id's from the Lead table.  I have tried INNER Joins to accomplish this, but always seem to output only the first id.

This is the latest query I have tried

```
SELECT `TeamMember`.`fname`,
       `TeamMember`.`lname`
  FROM `MaxusDash`.`Lead`
 INNER JOIN `MaxusDash`.`TeamMember`
    ON (`Lead`.`pmp` = `TeamMember`.`UID`)
   AND (`Lead`.`pms` = `TeamMember`.`UID`)
   AND (`Lead`.`ci_lead` = `TeamMember`.`UID`)
   AND (`Lead`.`av_lead` = `TeamMember`.`UID`)
   AND (`Lead`.`prod_lead` = `TeamMember`.`UID`)
   AND (`Lead`.`f_lead` = `TeamMember`.`UID`)
   AND (`Lead`.`sec_lead` = `TeamMember`.`UID`)
 WHERE `Lead`.`pid` = 44;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your current query says all those ids have to point to the same user in each row. You might want to use `OR` instead, but you will probably get duplicates and have to handle that.

Comment: Of-topic but it would seem you would benefit from a slight table re-design or addition after seeing your code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to return all the names on a single row, then you'd need to use a separate join operation for each foreign key relationship.

But it appears you want to return each name on a separate row.

One approach is something like this:

```
 SELECT r.role
      , m.fname
      , m.lname
   FROM `MaxusDash`.`Lead` l
  CROSS
   JOIN (           SELECT 'pmp' AS `role`
          UNION ALL SELECT 'pms'
          UNION ALL SELECT 'ci_lead'
          UNION ALL SELECT 'av_lead'
          UNION ALL SELECT 'prod_lead'
          UNION ALL SELECT 'f_lead'
          UNION ALL SELECT 'sec_lead'
        ) r
   LEFT     
   JOIN `MaxusDash`.`TeamMember` m
     ON ( m.uid = l.pmp       AND r.role = 'pmp'       )
     OR ( m.uid = l.pms       AND r.role = 'pms'       )
     OR ( m.uid = l.ci_lead   AND r.role = 'ci_lead'   )
     OR ( m.uid = l.av_lead   AND r.role = 'av_lead'   )
     OR ( m.uid = l.prod_lead AND r.role = 'prod_lead' )
     OR ( m.uid = l.f_lead    AND r.role = 'f_lead'    )
     OR ( m.uid = l.sec_lead  AND r.role = 'sec_lead'  )

  WHERE l.pid = 44
```

Depending on the characterset of the `role` column, and your connection, you may need to specify (override the default) characterset of the string literals. For example, if the `role` is `latin1`, and your connection is UTF8, to avoid an "illegal mix of collations" error, you can preface the string literals with **`_latin1`**

```
                    SELECT _latin1'pmp' AS `role`
          UNION ALL SELECT _latin1'pms'
```

Remove the `r.role` expression from the SELECT list, if we don't need that value returned. Remove the `LEFT` keyword to use an inner join instead of an outer join.

Answer (score 0):

You have use `UNION` or create a `JOIN` for each lead member

**UNION:**

```
SELECT `pmp` as lead, `TeamMember`.`fname`, `TeamMember`.`lname`
FROM `MaxusDash`.`Lead`
INNER JOIN `MaxusDash`.`TeamMember` 
        ON (`Lead`.`pmp` = `TeamMember`.`UID`) 
WHERE `Lead`.`pid`=44
UNION  
SELECT `pms` as lead, `TeamMember`.`fname`, `TeamMember`.`lname`
FROM `MaxusDash`.`Lead`
INNER JOIN `MaxusDash`.`TeamMember` 
        ON (`Lead`.`pms` = `TeamMember`.`UID`) 
WHERE `Lead`.`pid`=44
UNION  
....
UNION
SELECT `sec_lead` as lead, `TeamMember`.`fname`, `TeamMember`.`lname`
FROM `MaxusDash`.`Lead`
INNER JOIN `MaxusDash`.`TeamMember` 
        ON (`Lead`.`sec_lead` = `TeamMember`.`UID`) 
WHERE `Lead`.`pid`=44
```

**JOIN**

```
SELECT `pmp`.`fname`, `pmp`.`lname`,
       `psp`.`fname`, `psp`.`lname`,
       ....
       `sec_lead`.`fname`, `sec_lead`.`lname`
FROM `MaxusDash`.`Lead` as `L`
INNER JOIN `MaxusDash`.`TeamMember` as `pmp`
        ON L.`pmp` = `pmp`.`UID`

INNER JOIN `MaxusDash`.`TeamMember` as `psp`
        ON L.`psp` = `psp`.`UID`

....
INNER JOIN `MaxusDash`.`TeamMember` as `sec_lead`
        ON L.`sec_lead` = `sec_lead`.`UID`

WHERE `L`.`pid`=44
```

Comment: The UNION solution works as well, however the constant need to insert the pid= was not a fit for my application.  Thank you for the help as well!